# MSBuild fails with missing reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, dll, msbuild

There are similar questions on here, but I've exhausted every solution i've found for this issue.

My solution compiles and runs fine locally, but when I check in my code and MSBuild runs, it fails with the error `The type or namespace name 'DbUp' could not be found`.

`DbUp` is available on Nuget, but I had to use a modified version that I received so I dragged it into my packages folder manually and then referenced it by browsing to the `.dll` in the project.

I first tried to fix this issue by deleting the `.dll` and trying to reference it again. Then I deleted the whole project and tried the process again. Still, everytime, it compiles and runs fine locally, but fails everytime when I check in my code and run MSBuild.

I checked out project file and the reference appears to be in there fine:

```
<Reference Include="DbUp">
    <HintPath>..\packages\dbup\DbUp.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The thing I don't understand is that I'll clean my solution and then recompile and `DbUp.dll` is in my bin. So why can't MSBuild find the reference?

Let me know if you need any additional information to help out. Thanks.

Comment: Is the packages folder under source control?

Comment: Yes, it is under source control

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building this on a build server. If that is the case, then the issue might be that the build server is not restoring the NuGet packages before  building the solution.

You can issue a NuGet restore before you build your solution after checkout. You might have to adjust paths the nuget.exe along with your solution.

```
nuget.exe restore <YourSolution>.sln
```

When the build process builds your solution, the packages should be there.

Comment: If you do a complete clean of your solution, also removing the output bin directory and renaming your local packages folder, does it compile?  Make sure restore packages is turned on your solution. Visual Studio is probably finding the dll in the bin directory and that is why it is compiling on your machine.

Comment: I've been doing the clean and removing the bin, but I haven't tried renaming the local packages folder. The version of `DbUp` that I am using is a modified version, not the same one on Nuget. If I do that then won't it grab the version from Nuget?

Comment: Sorry missed that part on it being modified and not a downloadable NuGet package.  You can check in that package folder into source control. Not the whole packages folder just the DbUp folder so that when the build server checks everything out, that modified package is there.

Comment: It appears to be in there, but I'm going to delete it and try again

Comment: Deleted it manually from source control and dragged the folder back in manually and it worked!